# What algorithm would you use for clustering based on people attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I'm pretty new in the field of machine learning (even if I find it extremely interesting), and I wanted to start a small project where I'd be able to apply some stuff.

Let's say I have a dataset of persons, where each person has N different attributes (only discrete values, each attribute can be pretty much anything).

I want to find clusters of people who exhibit the same behavior, i.e. who have a similar pattern in their attributes ("look-alikes").

How would you go about this? Any thoughts to get me started?

I was thinking about using PCA since we can have an arbitrary number of dimensions, that could be useful to reduce it. K-Means? I'm not sure in this case. Any ideas on what would be most adapted to this situation?

I do know how to code all those algorithms, but I'm truly missing some real world experience to know what to apply in which case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K-means using the n-dimensional attribute vectors is a reasonable way to get started. You may want to play with your distance metric to see how it affects the results.

Comment: How do you define the mean in this case, since my attributes can have totally arbitrary discret values?

Comment: The way people often model discrete values is by splitting them up into binary coded variables. For example, if you have a "Pet" field with possible values "cat" and "dog", you would recode that as 2 binary variables, "cat" and "dog".

Comment: I see thanks for the tip :) Since I will have a large number of dimensions, wouldn't it be useful to use PCA first to reduce the number of dimensions?

Comment: Yeah, PCA could help if you are trying to reduce the dimensionality of your space. How many dimensions do you have?

Comment: It's still WIP but each person could potentially have in the hundreds of attributes... What's the ratio for dimensionality reduction with PCA, what if I want to bring it back to 2 dimensions to be able to visualize "something" ?

Comment: Actually k-means isn't very sensible unless you are in Euclidean space. Of course you can hack around this with the cat/dog attributes, but that heavily biases your results, as there are not values inbetween of 0 and 1 in this attribute. K-means will then prefer strongly the splits "cats only" and "dogs only".

Comment: Is there another good clustering algorithm that would work better in case of discrete attributes?

Answer (score 2):

The first step to pretty much any clustering algorithm is to find a suitable distance function. Many algorithms such as `DBSCAN` can be parameterized with this distance function then (at least in a decent implementation. Some of course only support Euclidean distance ...).

So start with considering how to measure object similarity!

Comment: Let's say each attribute for a person is a numerical ID. I still can't use Euclidian distance, since ID n can correspond to something very different from n+1. Should I treat these numerical IDs as discrete values?

Comment: You *need* to define a sensible distance function. Whatever that may be for your particular data I cannot tell.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should also try expectation-maximization algorithm (also called [EM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm)). On the other hand, you must be careful while using PCA because this algorithm may reduce the dimensions relevant to clustering.

Comment: In which cases is it wise to use PCA as a kind of "preprocessing" of your data? I'm interested to know what makes you think that EM would be a good choice here, I know the algorithm but I have no idea when to use it.

Comment: I would prefer to use PCA when I do not have the output information because it is an unsupervised method. In such cases PCA is a good choice for dimensionality reduction. For EM algorithm, the first one it is probabilistic and you can find the component density parameters that maximize the likelihood of the sample in your hand. and the second is when I implemented and run it, I obtained more sensitive results comparing to k-means. However, i warn you because it may take a long time. On the other hand, i dont have any conceivable reason for EM :)